# Have lots of Async calls, how to make it faster?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a API call, inside the API call, it has lots of async calls. the code looks like:

```
.....
var getFeaturedTask = await _listingProxy.GetFeaturedListingsAsync(request);
var getRentalTask = await _listingProxy.GetRentalsAsync(request);
var getContactTask = await _contactProxy.GetLeadContactAsync(request);
var getSignTask = await _signProxy.GetListingSignsAsync(request);
var getTextTask = await _signProxy.GetTextCodeForListingAsync(request);
......
```

There are more than 20 tasks. I'm wondering whether there is a way to make this part of the code run faster. For example, should I use below code and it will be faster?

```
var getFeaturedTask = _listingProxy.GetFeaturedListingsAsync(request);
var getRentalTask = _listingProxy.GetRentalsAsync(request);
var getContactTask = _contactProxy.GetLeadContactAsync(request);
var getSignTask = _signProxy.GetListingSignsAsync(request);
......
Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { getFeaturedTask, getRentalTask, getContactTask, getSignTask, ... });
```

Any other possibilities? Or, no matter what, the time we may save is very small, not worth it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`WhenAll` is the appropriate way to do asynchronous concurrency:

```
var getFeaturedTask = _listingProxy.GetFeaturedListingsAsync(request);
var getRentalTask = _listingProxy.GetRentalsAsync(request);
var getContactTask = _contactProxy.GetLeadContactAsync(request);
var getSignTask = _signProxy.GetListingSignsAsync(request);
......
await Task.WhenAll(getFeaturedTask, getRentalTask, getContactTask, getSignTask, ...);
```

This block of code will run all the asynchronous requests concurrently. ***If*** they are truly asynchronous operations (i.e., not blocking with asynchronous signatures), *and* if they take long enough that the (small) additional overhead of `WhenAll` is overcome, *and* there are no additional throttling systems in place (i.e., if the proxies only allow one request at a time per IP or something like that), then this block should run faster.

Answer (score 2):

This largely depends on what the "proxies" are here. Some things support concurrent operations; some do not (meaning it'll fail if you try and issue a second async operation on the same object when the first has not completed, like you do with `_listingProxy` and `_signProxy`). And even if they do: sometimes concurrency improves performance (especially when the two requests are independent, in the best case routing to separate servers), in some scenarios concurrency will make no difference whatsoever, and in some (rare-ish) scenarios concurrency will have a *detrimental* effect on performance.

So: there's no real way to know *in the general case*, but you could certainly try it. The one thing I'd say for certain, though, is that you shouldn't use `Task.WaitAll`. You *could* use `await Task.WhenAll`, or `await` each in turn (but this risks unobserved exceptions if more than one fails).